# How to close Telegram poll (that was created by bot) after few days and manually

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

```
@Scheduled(cron = "* * * * * *")
private void sendFriPoll(){
    SendPoll sendPoll = new PollService().getPoll(String.valueOf(chatIdPoll), "friday");
    sendPoll.enableNotification();
    sendSchPoll(sendPoll);
}

private void sendSchPoll(SendPoll sendPoll){
    sendPoll.setChatId(String.valueOf(chatIdPoll));
    try {
        if (!isPollExist){
            execute(sendPoll);
            //isPollExist = true;
        }
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

How to close Telegram poll after few days if poll was created by bot?

Related with [close_date](https://core.telegram.org/api/poll)  max value is 600 sec.

```
 @Override
    public void onUpdateReceived(Update update)
```

Does not track updated from bot.

I have tried get ".getMessageId()" but I need new instance of "Update" and as I said "onUpdateReceived" does not tracked message from bot.
Also I tried send command for bot by bot.

I expect that poll will automatically closed after 2 days or I can close it with command /stop (using .getMessageId())

Answer (score 1):

Question is too old, but :)

You need to use `stopPoll`.

Details: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#stoppoll